# Clipboard change event in electron

Tags: javascript, events, clipboard, electron

I'd like to write a clipboard manager that monitors the systems' clipboard. Well I have found: https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/clipboard.md, but couldn't find any events for the clipboard.

Do clipboard events exist in electron? I mean like `QClipboard`'s `void selectionChanged()` and `void dataChanged()` or like GTK's owner-changed

Currently I'm retrieving the contents of the clipboard and look manually whether the content has changed every 20ms, which should not be the preferred way. It works but I really shouldn't resort to a busy polling loop...

Comment: not implemented yet, you can track the progress in https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2280

Comment: Support in electron depends on https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=933608

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Electron does not provide such event yet.

Currently Electron team waits for Chromium project to implement this feature first. But according to Chromium issue tracker they implemented only ChromeOS and X11 support and are not looking to implement it for Windows/MacOS.

You can find more information in feature request at: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2280

Answer (score 0):

Below you can see a simple example of how to attach event handlers to clipboard events.

```
['cut', 'copy', 'paste'].forEach(function(event) {
    document.addEventListener(event, function(e) {
        console.log(e);   
    });
});
```

Please note the `cut` and `paste` are working in proper editable areas.

This theme is commented in details here: https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2014/12/02/definitive-guide-copying-pasting-javascript/

Comment: Thanks. I probably should have added that the application is running in the background and has no focus. Since this is not supported by a browser's clipboard (and probably never will due to security reasons) electron has created another API I have referenced above. This is OK for a desktop environment like electron (security wise) because we are running it like a "native" one. I can capture all content through this API but in a busy polling style. Now qt's framework also targets desktop applications and also offers a clipboard API but with a signaling mechanism I would like to see in electron.